# scipy constrain non-x0 argument

Tags: python, scipy

Let's say I have the following function:

```
import scipy
def fitness(w, assets, rf=0., dt='2016-12-30'):
    mu = float(ptf_mean(assets,w,dt))
    sigma  = float(ptf_var(assets,w,dt)) 

    sigma_sum = sigma.sum()

    util = -(mu - rf) / (sigma)   
    return util
```

And:

```
b_ = [(0.,1.) for i in range(2)]
c_ = ({'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda w: sum(w)-1. }) 
optimized = scipy.optimize.minimize(fitness, np.matrix([1.,0.]), (assets, rf, dt), 
            method='SLSQP', constraints=c_,bounds=b_)
```

Now, let's say I want to constrain on `sigma_sum`. How could I go about doing that? All constraint examples I have seen in the docs only vary `x0` or `w` in my example.

I am leaving out defining `assets`, `rf` and `dt` as thye are not really related to the problem, but assume the code compilsed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`sigma_sum`  is a function of `w`  (and parameters). To constrain it means to constrain `w` so that `sigma_sum` satisfies some condition. This involves having a callable that returns the value involving `sigma_sum`, for example:

```
c2_ = ({'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda w: sigma_sum(w) - 42})
```

where `sigma_sum` is defined by

```
def sigma_sum(w, assets, rf=0., dt='2016-12-30'):
    mu = float(ptf_mean(assets,w,dt))
    sigma  = float(ptf_var(assets,w,dt)) 
    return sigma.sum()
```

To avoid code duplication, you'd probably want to use this `sigma_sum` in your function that is computing the objective.